# Function to get the most frequently appearing pixel

Tags: c, image, io

What i have so far is a nice and rapid algorithm for finding the pixel dominant from bmp image.
I am not sure how to make it to work.. i though it works, but the program freezes.

```
RGB
bitfox_get_primecolor_direct
(char *FILE_NAME)
{
    RGB primecolor;
    BYTE rgb[3];

    dword *counts = calloc(pow(256, 3), sizeof(*counts));
    dword max_count = 0;

    FILE* fp = fopen(convert(FILE_NAME), "rb");

    fseek(fp, 54, SEEK_SET);
    while (fread (rgb, sizeof(BYTE), 3, fp) != EOF)
    {
        dword idx = (((dword)rgb[0]) << 16) | (((dword)rgb[1]) << 8) | (dword)rgb[2];
        if (++counts[idx] > max_count) max_count = idx;
    }

    primecolor.R = (max_count >> 16) & 0xFF;
    primecolor.G = (max_count >> 8) & 0xFF;
    primecolor.B = max_count & 0xFF;

    free(counts);
    fclose(fp);
    return primecolor;
}
```

`BYTE` is `unsigned char`

`RGB` is struct containg `BYTE` R, G and B.

Comment: Not a C expert, but the `sizeof char` is always equal to 1 by definition, and this is interpreted by the C compiler to be one byte, by definition. However, this does not mean that the byte contains 8 bits, just a minimum of 8. So it is possible that `<< 16`, `>> 16`, `<< 8` and `>> 8` are not behaving as expected. But again, I'm no expert. See this discussion on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215445/are-there-machines-where-sizeofchar-1

Comment: 1 byte in my case is 8 bits. I have been messing with bit functions and stuff on my PC from long ago.

Answer (score 6):

There are numerous problems with the code. First of all, `fread` never returns EOF (which is -1). The loop should end when it reads less than 3 bytes.

Second, `max_count` is *index*, not a color value. I presume you meant `rgb[max_count]`.

Test a file pointer returned by `fopen` for not being NULL.

Test a return value of `fseek`.

Avoid magic numbers. I suppose 54 is a size of certain header. Create a constant with a meaningful name. Better yet, define a header structure and take its `sizeof`.

Comment: 54 is the offset of the pixel array of a bmp image.
54+ are pixels only.

Comment: I missed the `max_count` issue.  Good catch!

Answer (score 6):

I see some things here that could help you improve your code.

### Provide a full working example

This comment is really more about how to get a good code review rather than about the code itself.  The function as it is posted won't compile without supplying a number of missing things, including the appropriate `#include`s, `typedef`s for `BYTE` and `dword`, a `typedef` for a `struct RGB`, the function `convert()`, etc.

It would be easier to provide a good review if these things were supplied.

### Check your return values

The code calls `fopen` and then immediately does an `fseek`. What if either of those calls fails?  What if `calloc` fails?  The code doesn't currently check the return value, which could indicate a failure.  Better would be to check the return value and do the appropriate thing -- possibly by returning early.

### Check `fread`'s return value

The code *does* check the return value of `fread` but it's the wrong one.  Specifically, `fread` returns the number of items read, and so should be compared to the number of items that were attempted.  With that said, the line currently says:

```
while (fread (rgb, sizeof(BYTE), 3, fp) != EOF)
```

It might be better to write it this way:

```
while (fread (rgb, sizeof(rgb), 1, fp) == 1)
```

The difference is that instead of indicating that you're reading three `BYTE`s, this says that you're reading one `rgb` which is really what you're doing.  It also means that if the definition of `rgb` ever changes, you'll only have to change it once and this code will automatically get the right size for `rgb`.

### Be careful with index arrays

We don't know how `dword` is defined, but we can assert that `[]` only operates on `int` index values.  On a system in which `dword` is defined as, say, `unsigned long` but an `int` is shorter, this will cause a problem with this code.  You might want to add an `assert` to make sure that your indexing will actually work.

### Eliminate runtime calculation

The `pow(256, 3)` is executed at runtime every time this function is called.  Since it's simply 256*256*256, one could just as easily make that a `const` value that is calculated at compile time, saving a little time and code.

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

Things like `(maxcount >> 16) & 0xFF` are OK, because programmers reading this will know what that code is doing.  However, when you write `fseek(fp, 54, SEEK_SET)` it's not at all obvious whether 54 is the correct value, or exactly what it represents.  Better would be to use a named `const` value there such as `const long HEADER_SIZE = 54;`

### Consider optimizing the data structure

Right now the code allocates and deallocates 16M each time the routine is called.  That might not be a problem on your machine, but it's likely that it could be optimized for size and probably speed.  Since this is likely to be a sparse array (that is, most values will contain 0), you might consider storing only non-zero values, perhaps in a tree structure so that the top value is always at the root of the tree.  This will probably save memory and will likely also be faster since more of the data structure will be in the local cache.